# What is the best way for IPC in java?

Tags: java

I am using Netbeans for developing two separate application.

I need to communicate between two jar what is the best IPC Communication.

Comment: "It depends" - will the two applications run on the same host? On different hosts within the same local network? On different hosts on a wide area network? How large is your payload?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51452/best-practice-for-java-ipc

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There is never a *best* way to solve a problem. There is only the way which works best for *you*.

When you have two separate processes running on different hosts, you need to communicate via [network sockets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/). You could use an existing protocol standard like [SOAP](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/appdev.920/a96616/arxml11.htm). When you are sure that none of the two applications will ever be rewritten in a different programming language, you could also use [ObjectOutputStream and ObjectInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/objectstreams.html) connected to network sockets and exchange Java objects directly between the two programs. Or you could design your own protocol from scratch which is optimized for your application.

When the processes run on the same host, communicating via network is often still a good option. But there are others like communicating via writing and reading temporary files. You could also go the UNIX way, and have one application write to `System.out` and pipe its output to the other program which reads it with `System.in`.