# Return List<> from java Spark application

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have built an Java application which displays data fetched from database. i have built a JavaSpark application and built it as a jar. i give input to the Spark application through Spark Launcher as arguments. My javaSpark application fetches data from database and stores it as a List. how do i return the List to my main Java program

Main.java:

```
    public Static void Main(String[] args){
    String query = select fname,lname from people;
    SparkLauncher sl = new SparkLauncher();
    sl.Launcher(query);
//program to read from text file and display
..
    }
```

SparkLauncher.java:

```
public Launcher(){
Process spark = null;

            spark = new SparkLauncher()
                    .setSparkHome("D:\\spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.4")
                    .setAppResource("PeopleData-1.0.jar")                    
                    .addJar("D:\\mysql-connector-java-5.1.36.jar")                 
                    .addAppArgs(query)                    
                    .setMainClass("myapp.Main").setMaster("local[4]").launch();
 }
```

As of now my PeopleData.jar runs and writes in a text file and i read the text file from Main.java and display it. Is there a way that my PeopleData.jar returns the List to my Main.java so that the process of writing and reading is avoided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't launch Spark as a separate process, use [`JavaSparkContext`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaSparkContext.html) instead.

If you do have to launch it as a process, it doesn't matter it's a Spark application. There are many different ways to communicate between JVM processes: see [What is the best way for IPC in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21025017/what-is-the-best-way-for-ipc-in-java) and related questions.