# Is it possible to call static method from another application?

Tags: java

I have a class Server with infinite loop in main() and public static String method getStats(), server runs and store some info in static variables. I want to have another standalone application, which will be ran on the same machine and should show output of getStats(). I managed to call the method like this:

```
import server.Server;

class ServerStats
{
     public static void main(String[] args) {
        String response = Server.getStats();
        System.out.println(response);
     }
}
```

but it shows wrong (uninitialized) data for pretty obvious reasons.

So, is there any way to run Server's static method getStats() from ServerStats and get correct response or should I just write client-server interaction between them? Can anyone recommend some common patterns for solving such problem besides sockets and rmi?

Comment: Two different java programs means two different process. Process communicates with things such as socket/pipes/etc

Comment: Check this and his implementation in java [Web Service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service)

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51452/best-practice-for-java-ipc) on Java IPC best practices might prove useful.

Comment: Why "besides RMI"? This is the purpose of "Remote Method Invocation" (hence the name). Unless you want to re-invent the wheel, you should stick to a pre-existing framework.