# Data transfer between JVMs

Tags: java, memory, jvm

I have a Desktop tool with data of defined Strings and HashMaps loaded in RAM while running, I like to split the above as separate data and process tools so that data will be transfered between JVMs.

For Example, Data will be running as separate JVM and more than one JVM can communicate with Data JVM to transfer values.

Is that possible ?

Comment: I think you are looking our for map reduce paradigm ?

Comment: I want to use the data without manipulation... just as variable

Comment: One to many concept like one data tool and others are processing tools

Comment: Why don't you just use sockets ?

Comment: Yes, that is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You should look for **Inter process communication** (IPC) in Java. Find out the existing discussions about that..
[What is the best way for IPC in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21025017/what-is-the-best-way-for-ipc-in-java)
[Best practice for Java IPC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51452/best-practice-for-java-ipc)